# how to let \ref only show "(a)" instead of "6.8 (a)"?

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats

my \ref to the subfigure prints "6.8 (a)", which is right. But what if I only want the refer to the subfigure printed as "(a)"?

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \subfigure[naive approach]{
        \includegraphics[width = .43 \textwidth ]{Graphics/5Implement/featuremaps/intr12/z_ground.png}
        \label{fig:a}
    }
    \subfigure[xyr approach]{
        \includegraphics[width = .43 \textwidth ]{Graphics/5Implement/featuremaps/intr12/z_pre.png}
        \label{fig:b}
        }
    \caption{I want to ref the image as "a", this is the 6.8 Figure but as the caption of it own, there is no need to mention 6.8 like \ref{fig:a}}
    \label{fig:The_figure_itself_is_6.8}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Did you try subref?

Comment: @xxx--- `\subref` is mentioned in the answer I posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're using the `subfigure` package.  The `subfigure` package provides the command `\subref` with which you may achieve your typesetting objective.

**Aside:** The `subfigure` package is deprecated. Don't use it. Instead, use either the `subfig` or the `subcaption` package. Really. If you need a vivid proof for why it's advisable to *avoid* using the `subfigure` package, look closely at the first cross-referencing call-out in the example below: The figure number is not shown as "6.8" but as "8". Arggh.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{subfigure} % for \subfigure macro
\counterwithin{figure}{section} % just for this example

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{6} % just for this example
\setcounter{figure}{7} 

\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \subfigure[Naive approach]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{a.png}
        \label{fig:a}
        }%
    \hfill
    \subfigure[Sophisticated approach]{%
        \includegraphics[width=.47\textwidth]{b.png}
        \label{fig:b}
        }
    \caption{Two images}
    \label{fig:6.8}
\end{figure}
\noindent
As shown in figure \ref{fig:a}, \dots

\noindent
As shown in panel \subref{fig:a} of figure \ref{fig:6.8}, \dots
\end{document}
```